# Trying to grab multiple usernames and passwords from an ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

So I'm having difficulties figuring out why this isn't working but basically what I'm trying to do is grab user information so when they click login they are able to login.

```
private boolean login() {
    for (User user : users) {
        if (user != null) {
            System.out.println(users.size());
            String tryUser = user.getUsername();
            String tryPass = user.getPassword();
            String passText = new String(
                    LoginPanel.passwordPf.getPassword());

            if (LoginPanel.usernameTf.getText().equalsIgnoreCase(
                    tryUser)
                    && passText.equals(tryPass)) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

I checked the array and all the users are stored properly but for some reason when I try to get the username and password it grabs it from the first item in the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are always `return`ing in the loop, so you will never check any user beyond the first one. You should change your check:

```
if (LoginPanel.usernameTf.getText().equalsIgnoreCase(tryUser) && passText.equals(tryPass)) {
  return true;
}
// Do not return, check next user in list
// else {
//   return false;
// }
```

Answer (score 0):

Although it may seem intuitive to do the following:

```
} else {
    return false;
}
```

You should use "continue" to run your for loop over the next element.

```
} else {
    continue;
}
```

Comment: This does not make a lot of sense in this case, since there is no code after the if..else check, so the next iteration will begin right away, anyways.

Comment: I agree that it's loquacious, but I think the poster is new, and "continue" for loops are an important concept.